# UIView subclass not being deallocated

Tags: ios, uiview, nstimer, objective-c-2.0

I have a subclassed UIView which is not being deallocated. I know that only one class is creating an instance of my view. I have an NSTimer ivar in my view. If I comment out that timer and when I tap a cancel button that is on this view controller, dealloc in this view is called. If I don't comment out the timer, the dealloc is never called.

```
//CustomUIView
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _pollTimer = [[NSTimer scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(onPollTimerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
    }
}
```

I want to keep a reference to this timer because there are times when I wish to pause the timer. Now, I could have a property on my view for the timer and in the dealloc method of the class that has a reference to my custom uiview, I could invalidate it before releasing said view. I don't really like this approach because I don't want to expose this timer to outside entities.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: NSTimer retains it's target...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`NSTimer` always retains its target](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:). This has two implications:

1. You shouldn't have the view (which is the timer's target) retain the timer, as this will create a cycle.
2. Your view will never be deallocated so long as the timer remains active.

Instead, you should call `invalidate` on the timer whenever your view is done with it. Once this is done, the view will be `dealloc`ated when its reference count goes to zero.

Typically this happens when a view is removed from its superview; if you want it to keep using its timer until that happens and then get released, you can override `removeFromSuperview` to invalidate the timer and then call `super`.

Comment: How can this answer only have one upvote? (Well, two now...) Overriding removeFromSuperview was the key for me, thanks Rickster.

Answer (score 0):

## Edit:

In your `-dealloc` method, try this:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [_pollTimer invalidate];

    /*
        If not using ARC:
        [_pollTimer release], _pollTimer = nil;
        [super dealloc];
    */
}
```

---

You have forgotten to call `super`'s implementation of `-initWithFrame:`! Whoops!

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        _pollTimer = [[NSTimer scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(onPollTimerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
    }
    
    return self;
}
```

This should work much better.

Comment: actually, I am doing that. sorry forgot to but that in my code snippet.

Comment: If NSTimer is retaining its target, the retain count will not hit zero, and therefore the object won't be `dealloc`ed. You need to take that code out of dealloc and call it elsewhere when you're done with this view.

Answer (score 0):

You should not retain the timer. Schedule the timer like this : `_pollTimer = [NSTimer scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(onPollTimerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];` and whenever you want to invalidate it: `[_pollTimer invalidate]`